# Target specific instance of the same label while parsing JSON

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to grab the price for each of these two beverages and have them display for their respective sizes on a website:

```
"Beverage":{
    "BeverageA":[{
        "Prices":[{
            "Id":"A",
            "Size":"5.0",
            "Price":"2.0"
        },{
            "Id":"B",
            "Size":"16.0",
            "Price":"4.75",
        }],
    }],
    "BeverageB":[{
        "Prices":[{
            "Id":"A",
            "Size":"5.0",
            "Price":"2.5"
        },{
            "Id":"B",
            "Size":"16.0",
            "Price":"5.0",
        }],
    }],
}
```

Since both beverages use the "Id, Size, and Price" labels I can't create a variable in PHP to grab that particular value like I normally would:

```
foreach ($json_taps as $beverage) {
    $a_price = $beverage['Beverage']['Prices']['Price'];
    $b_price = $beverage['Beverage']['Prices']['Price'];

$html =
    //Display the price of beverage a
    $a_price.

    ' '.

    //Display the price of beverage b
    $b_beverage

echo $html;
}
```

Since this would not allow me to target which of the two specific beverages, this doesn't work.

I thought about trying something like:

```
foreach ($json_taps as $beverage) {
     $id = $beverage['Beverage']['Prices']['Id'];
     $price = $beverage['Beverage']['Prices']['Price'];


$html =
    //Check for Id A
    if ($id = "A") {
        //Display price of A
        $price
    };

    //Check for Id B
    if ($id = "B") {
        //Display price of B
        $price
    };

echo $html;
}
```

But obviously, this doesn't work, either.

Just looking to be able to target two instances of the same label separately to be displayed on the page. For this example I have simplified DigitalPour's JSON file.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

An attempt at listing beverages and their variant/prices acording to the last JSON structure provided :

```
$html = '';

foreach ($json_taps['Beverage'] as $beverage_name => $beverage) {
    $html .= $beverage_name.' ';

    foreach ($beverage[0]['Prices'][0] as $variant) {
        $html .= $variant['Size'].':'.$variant['Price'];
    }

}

echo $html;
```

You could easily access individual beverages instead of looping over them if that's not what you need, like so :

```
$beverageA = $json_taps['Beverage']['BeverageA']; // see code above inside first loop
$beverageB = $json_taps['Beverage']['BeverageB']; // etc...
```

Comment: I know this wasn't included in the original issue, but this solution isn't working for me because there is already a loop in place for the different beverages. Nesting the loops breaks the site. I wish that I could change there JSON file. There have been a few odd things that I wish that I could have changed. However, it is generated by a third party who will not change it for us.

Comment: I see your last edit, the JSON structure has changed a lot, makes a lot more sense that way. Updating the answer acordingly, no extra loop.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think about the issue with nesting the loops, so I didn't include it in the original question.

Comment: well, for the sake of genericity I still looped over the beverages array but added how to access individual beverages afterwards. Hope that helps.

Comment: Not working for me :-(. Probably something in my question. I have dumped the json output for one beverage and my php file into a jsfiddle (link below). I'm trying to get the beverage ID so I can make each size into a different span that I can then label. And then display the price of that beverage. JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jagmz2fL/1/ Page in action csbrew.com/tap-list

Comment: I sort of have it now, but it's only hooking into the last item in the array. Ideas?

Comment: Now looking at your original json file thanks to the jsfiddle link, I noticed everything you seem to be looking for is not located under the "Beverage" key, as mentioned in the question and the last edit. That may or may not be the problem you're encountering now with your code, I can only guess here.

Comment: Yeah, it's under ['MenuProductDisplayDetail']['Beverage']['Prices']['Price']. I got it almost all of the way by doing $variant = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Prices'];
 foreach ($variant as $pricing) {
  $beverage_id = $pricing['Id'];
  $beverage_price = $pricing['Price'];
  $beverage_output =
   '<span class="pricing-container">'.
    '<span class="beverage-id-'.$beverage_id.'"> - '.
     '$'.$beverage_price.
    '</span>'.
   '</span>'; 
  } but this is only displaying the fourth value, not all of them sequentially.

Comment: because you're affecting the html to the `$beverage_output` variable (`=`), not appending (`.=`). Everything should be fine after that fix.

Comment: It always comes down to a missing punctuation mark, doesn't it? Now I'm getting prices for each beverage added to the previous one as the list goes on, though. Im assuming it has something to do with the initial loop and tying it in with the second loop. Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jagmz2fL/2/